How to randomise instance positions on a plane? Currently they appear as if vertical/ diagonal formation
I encountered this issue for the first time while instancing. The instances seem to have lined up and not appearing in a random way.
As it is visible in images shared, the houses (instances) on the city grid have lined up perfectly by same type somehow.
How can I randomise the instance output?


Strangely enough, the file I downloaded has randomised instances, not perfectly lined up. A few of them are just slightly lower than the others below the plane, but apart from that I see no issue in the distribution of instances.

I think that's my live save file :D

Well, since you got your answer I guess it does not matter... otherwise this link will only confuse people. By the way, you can upload a file at https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question... then there is no risk of making it useless for the question.

In the following example I random-translate the instances to offset them somewhat and thus no longer a uniform brigade:


EDIT: if you want them on the same plane (z-location) you should instead set the Random type to Vector, and only vary the X and Y min/max params and keep z=0 for min and max.
EDIT-2: per your comment below I have added a random into the Instance Index of Instances on Points:



The nodetree relies down the line on the symmetry of square instances so offsetting them would upset the raycasting nodes that I set up. Which is why I used mesh to points on the grind instead of distribute. Also the issue is not about spacing or translation of instances, the issue is about the choice of instances used by system amongst the ten instance choices i have fed it. So for example, all the stadiums, all the highrises and all the water tankers have lined up either horizontally or diagonally

@samar --  Use a random int (1-8?) into the "Instance Index" port of your "Instance on Points".  I edited to supply my change to your file.

Ok thanks, that solves it. Is the value 1-8 based on the number of types of instances i used ?

@samar -- yes.  but I'm a relative GN newbie and scratching my head that max>8 also looks good!  I would have expected some "empty lots" (the Detroit suburbs look, LOL)
